# Using Eclipselink history policy with inheritance type join

Tags: inheritance, jpa, glassfish, history, eclipselink

I would like to use eclipse link history to mirror the following to classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@TableGenerator(name="Employee_Gen", table="ID_GEN", pkColumnName="GEN_NAME", valueColumnName="GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue="Employee_Gen")
@Customizer(EmployeeCustomizer.class)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
}

@Entity
@Table(name="COMMESSIONEMPLOYEE")
public class CommesionEmployee extends Employee {
    }
```

where my history tables are

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE_HISTORY")
@IdClass(EmployeeHistoryId.class)
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class EmployeeHistory implements Serializable {
}

@Entity
@Table(name="COMMISSIONEMPLOYEE_HISTORY")
public class CommesionEmployeeHistory extends EmployeeHistory {
  }
```

and the customizer class is

```
public class EmployeeCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) throws Exception {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addStartFieldName("MJSTART");
        policy.addEndFieldName("EMPLOYEE.MJEND");
        //policy.addEndFieldName("COMMISSIONEMPLOYEE.CEEND");
        policy.addHistoryTableName("EMPLOYEE","EMPLOYEE_HISTORY");
        //policy.addHistoryTableName("COMMISSIONEMPLOYEE","COMMISSIONEMPLOYEE_HISTORY");
        policy.setShouldHandleWrites(true);
        cd.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

Currently nothing is being written to the COMMESSIONEMPLOYEE_HISTORY table. What am I doing wrong here?

P,S> If I use single table for inheritance for class EmployeeHistory nothing will be written to properties of the subclass ComessionEmployeeHistorry.

Answer (score 0):

Odd.

Try customizing both classes.

```
public class EmployeeCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) throws Exception {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addStartFieldName("MJSTART");
        policy.addEndFieldName("MJEND");
        policy.addHistoryTableName("EMPLOYEE","EMPLOYEE_HISTORY");
        policy.setShouldHandleWrites(true);
        cd.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}  

public class CommesionEmployeeCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) throws Exception {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addStartFieldName("MJSTART");
        policy.addEndFieldName("MJEND");
        policy.addHistoryTableName("COMMISSIONEMPLOYEE","COMMISSIONEMPLOYEE_HISTORY");
        policy.setShouldHandleWrites(true);
        cd.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

But, also log a bug, your errors don't seem right.